# What's the definition of algebraic quotient

Tags: algebra-precalculus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder says

> Given an integer a and a non-zero integer d, it can be shown that there exist unique integers q and r, such that a = qd + r and 0 ≤ r < |d|. The number q is called **the quotient**, while r is called the remainder.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient says

> In arithmetic, a quotient (from Latin: quotiens 'how many times', pronounced /ˈkwoʊʃənt/) is a quantity produced by the division of two numbers.The quotient has widespread use throughout mathematics, and is commonly referred to as the integer part of a division (in the case of Euclidean division), or as a fraction or a ratio (in the case of proper division).

So, consider this case `-1 / 2`, in terms of the first definition, the quotient should be `-1` since `-1 = -1*2 + 1`. However, in common sense, `-1/2` also equals `-0.5`. So, when we are saying algebraic quotient, which result is so-called the quotient?

Comment: As you quoted yourself ("or as fraction"), an algebraic quotient can have several meanings. For me, an algebraic quotient is of the form $G/H$ for an algebraic group $G$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156963/quotient-of-an-algebraic-group-by-a-closed-algebraic-subgroup). The book is called "Algebraic Quotients, Torus Actions, and Cohomology". But here,  $-1/2$ is just the fraction, if you ask me.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So, what result would you give when I ask what the quotient of `-1 /2` is? `-0.5` or `-1`?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since `-1/2` itself is the quotient, why we could get the quotient `-1` according to the first definition? I don't understand this point.

Comment: There is a reason pages like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_(disambiguation) exist, and it is because the same term has many meanings, and which one you should use depends what context you are in. It all depends on what you are doing and what you need it for.